# Уникальность столбцов SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть база данных, в которой есть список сообщений для каждой ветки обсуждений.

Например,

| Номер сообщения | Ветка |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | dev |
| 2 | dev |
| 1 | cat |

Очевидно, что комбинация (номер сообщения, ветка) должна быть уникальной. Я так и написал `unique(id, board)`, однако SQL считает их уникальными по отдельности, а нужна уникальность совокупности. Как это исправить?

Полный текст

```
create table threads
(
    id serial primary key,
    board varchar(5) not null
        constraint board_id_fk
            references boards
                on update cascade on delete cascade,
    subject text,
    message text not null,
    attachments jsonb,
    unique(board, id)
);
```

Comment: Я без понятия, что я сделал, но (вроде бы) все работает, но я все равно, хочу узнать, как это по серьезному делается

Answer (score 0):

Ограничение на пару `board, id` не имеет смысла, так как у вас есть ограничение уникальности (в виде первичного ключа) на `id`